# Determining if a specific url is present on an external website

Tags: php, search, external

How can I go about seeing if a particular website has a specific link in its content?  We have a situation where someone is not necessarily stealing our copyrighted content, but they are posting parts of it and linking to another site as the author and we're wanting to track each time they do this.

Basically what I need is something that will go to www.site_of_thieves.com/specific_page.php and search for www.second_site.com and report back on the number of matches found.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a program to do this automatically? If not, why not load the page in your browser, view the source and search the source for the text "www.second_site.com"? If something automated, do you also want to write this in PHP or is the PHP tag in reference to the thieving web site?

Comment: I should've been more clear -- I'm looking to create a PHP snippet that would do this for me.  I think Luca down below has nailed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$theivesSiteContent = file_get_contents("www.site_of_thieves.com/specific_page.php");

preg_match_all('/www.second_site.com/g', $theivesSiteContent, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

$cl> curl site.com | grep "the link"